# htmlWebpackPlugin parse ejs tag error

Tags: javascript, html-webpack-plugin

JS code

```
const ejs = require("ejs");
ejs.delimiter = '$';
cms.set("view engine","html");
cms.engine("html",ejs.__express);
```

ejs code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><$= title $></title>
</head>
<body class="cms-body">
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
new htmlWebpackPlugin({            
    filename: path.join(_rootpath, "/views/home.html"),
    template: path.join(_rootpath, "/views/template/home.ejs"),
    chunks:["vendor","home"],
    minify:{
        collapseWhitespace:true
    }
})
```

But page show :

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Parse Error: <$= title $>
```

I want to know HtmlWebpackPlugin how to skip the parse `<$= $>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the ejs server side you could rename

```
/views/template/home.ejs
```

to

```
/views/template/home.html
```

and rename

```
/views/home.html
```

to

```
/views/home.ejs
```

Then change your view engine to ejs.